# jQuery Toggle interfering wth IF statement

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

So I am coding a one page step by step booking process.
I have coded it so that when a button is clicked the content will toggle down.

This seems to have interfered with my VB.NET IF Statement behind one of the button click events as now the IF statement does not work.
It should show a div if something is not selected.

Can someone guide me on what to do please?

HTML:

```
<section>

  <div class="ChooseDoctor">    
    <div class="col-md-50 col-sm-50" style="text-align:center;">
      <h2>Choose your doctor</h2>

      <div class="alert alert-warning" id="warninginfo" runat="server">
        <strong>Warning!</strong> You have not selected your chosen doctor!
      </div> 

      <br />

      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [FirstName], [Surname], [DoctorNumber], [ContactNumber] FROM [DoctorDetails]">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
      <div class="col-md-50 col-sm-50" style="text-align:center;">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="DoctorNumber" Height="411px" Width="824px" ShowHeader="False" HorizontalAlign="Center">
          <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
          <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorNumber" HeaderText="DoctorNumber" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DoctorNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="Forename" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname" />
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowSelectButton="True" SelectImageUrl="~/Images/buttonforbooking.png" />
          </Columns>        
        </asp:GridView>

        <br /> 

        <asp:Button ID="btnNextDate" runat="server" Text="Next Step" OnClientClick="return false;" BackColor="#02bdd5" ForeColor="#ffffff" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-send" Height="55px" Width="211px" Align="Center"/>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Code-Behind File:

```
warninginfo.Visible = False

 btnNextDate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNextDate.Click
If GridView1.SelectedValue = Nothing Then
    warninginfo.Visible = True
End If
```

JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("[id$=btnNextDate]").click(function () {
        $("[id$=ChooseDate]").slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure about this syntax: `[id$=btnNextDate]` ? You can use this normal way: `$("#btnNextDate").click...` and remember it does not work if you use a master page.

Comment: The toggle will not work without that syntax, I think it's something to do with "runat=server". And what doesn't work if i use master page..jQuery?

Comment: Because if you use a master page the id is not same as the client id. And for js/jquery you need client id.

Comment: I do not see 'chooseDate' in your code ???

Comment: So if I am using a Master Page (navbar and footer) for say 4 pages, I can't use jQuery at all then?

Comment: You can ... But you must to use client id of elements. Do you need this?

Comment: ChooseDate is the Div for the content i want to show, i forgot to copy it in but it is under the button tag.

Comment: And yes I need it

Answer (score 0):

You must change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{       
   $('#' + '<%= btnNextDate.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#' + '<%= ChooseDate.ClientID %>').slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

To use client id, instead of server id. Just now I tried this and worked successfully.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette ... Thanks for the edit.. It seems I will not learn English Grammar  :D

Comment: Why?  Is your jquery link true? Is the `ChooseDate` a server side element?

Comment: I took the OnClientClick out and the IF statement worked, but once i selected an item in GridView and clicked for it to toggle, it would not toggle

Comment: Items in gridview?? There is no relation between you jquery code and the gridview items...

Comment: @ShannenLyons jQuery runs on client side... You should know!

Comment: @FarzinKanzi Either way it will not toggle for me

Comment: Sorry but you have problem in some where else. If the `ChooseDate` is server side, and your jquery link is true, So on click on `btnNextDate` the `ChooseDate` must toggle. Set an `alert('Hi')` after `document .ready` to see if it works?

Comment: I have decided to change this in vb.net so that they have to go to another page. I never realised that jQuery will not work if there is a MasterPage. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I never said such thing!!!! I said you must use client id... That we all do. If you inspect the element with the browser you will see that its id is some thing like this: `contentPlaceHolder1_btnNextDate` it is the client id that jquery/js work with.

Comment: Yep your right.. id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNextStep"... so what does that mean?

Comment: `<%= btnNextDate.ClientID %>` will give you the same. Or you can do this directly: `$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNextStep').click....` and do the same for `ChooseDate` (firstly inspect it also) . Did you change your code as the last update of answer?

Comment: I got confused. It is true now... Please test this.

Comment: Until now we work on **btnNextDate** . What is the **btnNextStep** ??

Comment: I will get back to you tomorrow, as I have had to log off for the night. Thanks

Comment: @FarzinKanzi,  do you happen to know, does ASP mess with the class names defined with `CssClass="..."` in the same way you describe for IDs?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 No, it does not.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi, thank you. I can now post my own answer ...... You are a kind and generous person ;)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would find the required element relative to the clicked button, which is pretty trivial if they are sibling nodes. DOM traversal is surprisingly efficient compared with finding nodes within the entire DOM.

I would also use classes, not ids, which are somewhat cumbersome here.

First :

- add `nextDate` to the button's class list
- add `chooseDate` to the ChooseDate div's class list.

Now write the click handler as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.nextDate").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Maybe required, maybe not?
        $(this).siblings(".chooseDate").slideToggle('slow'); // Find the required element relative to the clicked button. DOM traversal is very efficient.
    });
});
```

Unless the ids are needed for other reasons, they can disappear.

No idea whether this will prevent the interference with your VB.NET `IF` statement, but it's worth trying with and without the `e.preventDefault();` statement.

Comment: I must apologize for my misunderstanding: When I saw your comment *do you happen to know....* , for my bad english I was thinking this is offensive!! When i just now googled it, I see that this is a **polite way to ask some thing** --my fool-- .. And as the answer: I know that we can do this by **className**, but I tried to show him  how to use client id. This is more related to his question and maybe useful for other users.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi, I didn't feel I was owed an apology, but thank you anyway.